# How do I Implement the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET WEB API Application?

Tags: entity-framework-core, unit-of-work, repository-design

I am new to Entity Framwrok.

I have this pattern so far.

1- IRepository

Here is the class

```
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        T Get(long id);
        void Insert(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    }
```

2- Repository class :

```
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        private readonly DBContext context;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        private DbSet<T> entities;
        public Repository(DBContext context, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            entities = context.Set<T>();
        }
        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
           
            return entities.AsEnumerable();

        }
        public T Get(long id)
        {
            return entities.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
        }
        public void Insert(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }
            entities.Add(entity);
            unitOfWork.Complete();
        }
        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }
            unitOfWork.Complete();
        }
        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }
            entities.Remove(entity);
            unitOfWork.Complete();
        }
        public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

3- IUnitOfWork

```
    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        void Complete();
        void Dispose();
    }
```

4- UnitOfWork

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
    {
        readonly DBContext _dbContext;
        public IRepositoryEmployeeBank EmployeeBank { get;  set; }
        

        public UnitOfWork(DBContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            EmployeeBank = new RepositoryEmployeeBank(dbContext);

        }
        public void Complete()
        {
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _dbContext.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Let us say we have an entity in our app called EmployeeBank

What I added

5- IRepositoryEmployeeBank

```
 public interface IRepositoryEmployeeBank
    {
    }
```

6- RepositoryEmployeeBank

```
 public class RepositoryEmployeeBank : IRepositoryEmployeeBank
    {
        public RepositoryEmployeeBank( DbContext dbContext)
        {
            DbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public DbContext DbContext { get; }
    }
```

Now let us say we have an api controller called EmployeeBankController

How do I implement GetALl Methods ?

```
public class EmployeeBankController : Controller
    {
        public IUnitOfWork unitOfWork { get; set; }

        public EmployeeBankController(IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork)
        {
            unitOfWork = _unitOfWork;
        }

        [Route("[action]")]
        [HttpGet]
        public List<dynamic> List()
        {
            List<dynamic> model = new List<dynamic>();
            unitOfWork.// ForEach(a =>
            {
                var EmployeeBank = new
                {
                    ID = a.ID,
                    Name = a.Name,
                    Active = a.IsActive,
                    IbanNumber = a.IBAN
                };
                model.Add(EmployeeBank);
            });

            return model.ToList();
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Don't** implement generic-repository (anti-pattern) **nor** unit-of-work: your `DbContext` already is the unit-of-work and `DbSet<T>` is the generic-repository type. **You don't need to do anything, it's already done for you by EF**.

Comment: What is the purpose of `class BaseEntity`? (In my experience, entity-types should be POCOs that don't inherit from anything - and you should not be (ab)using inheritance just for common-functionality or common properties even if they represent different things (I agree C# _direly_ needs first-class mixins, but until then you shouldn't compromise your model like that).

Comment: @Dai that is my level of underating, but my boss do not want to inject repository in the controller, he wants unit of work instead it is my first time I see this pattern any ways to survive but what is the poinf of having the IRepositoryEmployeeBank

Comment: Your boss is incorrect. Besides, you should not be injecting a unit-of-work into a controller: a unit-of-work's lifespan should be a single-method, not the controller's lifetime (which has a lifespan of the entire request) - how else will do you multiple operations with only a single unit-of-work?

Comment: I will discuss with him what he needs exactly